# Simplifying $\frac {56+29i}{9-4i}$

Tags: complex-numbers

How would I simplify this expression?
$$\frac {56+29i}{9-4i}$$

I thought about doing this: 
$$  \frac {56+29i}{9-4i} \times \frac {56-29i}{56-29i} \times \frac {9+4i}{9+4i}  $$

is it right?

Comment: You're almost right, you just wouldnt need to multiply by $\frac {56-29i}{56-29i}$ Conjugation multiplication cancels out the imaginary parts as you seem to know and you only need to remove this from the demominator. Nothing here needs 'solving' but just simplifying by the way unless there' s more to it as you've only supplied an expression.

Comment: @JackPedley Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want $\frac {56-29i}{56-29i}$? You just want an integer in the denominator, and that can be achieved by multiplying by $\frac{9+4i}{9+4i}$. 
$$4+5i$$ would be the answer.